# error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certifi' python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Instalé Python y el módulo de Selenium en mi máquina, la cuál tiene Windows 10, y estoy tratando de hacer un proyecto el cuál nesesita el módulo de Selenium. Hago la importación del código desde consola y pero me arroja una serie de errores. El proyecto que voy ha hacer lo voy a realizar en Chrome y no sé porque me sale error en las librerias de Firefox, ¿Qué debo hacer?

Aquí el error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\**********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\\**********\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 28, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver, WebElement
  File "C:\Users\\**********\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .remote_connection import RemoteConnection
  File "C:\Users\\**********\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 24, in <module>
    import certifi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certifi'
```

Answer (score 0):

NO es un error propieamente tal del webdriver. Por alguna razon no esta instalado el modulo `certifi`, puedes instalarlo usando el comando:

```
pip install certifi
```

Esto tambien significa que pueden fallar otros modulos sin cargar si algo en las dependencias no esta funcionando. Si sigue dando errores, considera volver a instalar selenium webdriver.

SI existen problemas con las dependencias, tambien puedes intentar realizar una actualizacion de `pip` (el instalador de paquetes)

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```